# Слайд-переходы между представлениями

Tags: objective-c, ios

Слайд по прикосновению (как в фотопленке, только для представлений) в iOS-приложении. Я пытался сделать все вручную (расчитывал вектор скорости, движение фреймов) - заколебался, может существует готовое решение? На форумах пишут, что можно через `UINavigationViewController`? В `UIView` же доступно только 4 вида анимации (перевороты и перелистывания). Еще слышал про `CATransition`.

Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: Как в  фотопленке - это как? Вам нужен такой переход при переключении между UIViewController или где?

Comment: Мне такой переход нужен между обычными представлениями в Multi View Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно переходить по `View`'кам имено по касаниям (посредством простого листания пальцем), тогда лучше использовать `UIScrollView`, иногда `UIPageView`.

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделал